# Cleaning image and identifying brain parts from tomography opencv2

Tags: python, opencv

I have an assignment to do which is given a tomography image i have to remove anything but the brain and also find the left and right hemisphere of the brain by painting or extracting them.

Examples of tomography
[tomography1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyyMe.jpg)
[tomography2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoTLE.jpg)

Any ideas??

Comment: Perhaps this might give you some ideas. Skip the part about removing the borders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850305/opencv-segmentation-of-largest-contour-in-breast-mammograms/64850831#64850831

Comment: I would think that fitting an ellipse through the white region on the outside of the brain would be the most productive.

Comment: @fmw42 i'm getting an error at "result[mask==0] = (0,0,0)", NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 62732 output values where the mask is true. I don't usually use python so i'm kinda lost

Comment: @bfris thanks but I have no idea how to do that, I'm a beginner at cv2.

Comment: `@Lawzin` I would have to see your full code to see where there is an issue.

Comment: @fmw42 it's the exact same code from the link, i only changed source image

Comment: I still need to see your code for typos

Answer (score 1):

I will post my reply here even though is more like a comment (I don't have enough points to comment on posts).

Are you obliged to use Python and OpenCV?
Why don't you use [Freesurfer](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/)? I work with MRI images but it makes all the steps you cited automatically using `reconall` function.

1. https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/recon-all
2. https://andysbrainbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FreeSurfer/FS_ShortCourse/FS_03_ReconAll.html

Comment: yes, i can only use opencv and math libs. thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, I see! Then, I'll follow this thread since it can be quite interesting for me as well! I'll be back to you if I'll find something interesting :D